# How can I create a Text wiget in Tkinter, Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted to make a text wiget in window, but saw this traceback:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/хрень на питоне/experement3.py", line 18, in <module>
    vl=Text(root, width = 20, heigth = 100 , wrap = WORD)
  File "C:\Users\Людмилп\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3554, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'text', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Людмилп\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-heigth"
```

My code looked like this:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
app=Frame(root)
app.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=S)
bt=Button(app,text='''
First button
''')
bt.grid()
app1=Frame(root)
app1.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=S)
bt1=Button(app1,text='''
Second button
''')
bt1.grid()
vlf=Frame(root)
vlf.grid(row=0,column=3)
vl=Text(root, width = 20, heigth = 100 , wrap = WORD)
vl.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

What could went wrong?

Comment: Read the error closely, and check the spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Please read your error messages carefully because they almost ever contain useful information. In this case it tells you that in line 18 where you initialise the Text widget you give it an option "heigth" which it can't take. This is due to the fact that you just misspelled "height" by switching "t" and "h" which can happen and is just human.

PS: Your english isn't bad, don't worry. ^^

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It was my first question and I'm very happy that someone nice like you answered so fast :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. But please keep in mind that your answer still can be tagged as "Just a typing mistake" or something like that.